# Kotlin/Compose: Why won't my lazyColumn scroll?

Tags: kotlin, scroll, lazycolumn, lazylist

I stuffed it full of things, but can't get to the ones past the screen.  Been watching youtube videos, asking chatGpt, etc, and can't figure it out.  New to coding; sorry if this is an inefficient mess:

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    navigateToWordEntry: () -> Unit,
    navigateToWordUpdate: (Int) -> Unit,
    navigateToGame: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: DictionaryViewModel = viewModel(factory = AppViewModelProvider.Factory)
) {
    val dictionaryUiState by viewModel.dictionaryUiState.collectAsState()

    val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.enterAlwaysScrollBehavior()

    Scaffold(
        modifier = modifier.nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
        topBar = {
            VokabTopAppBar(navigateToGame=navigateToGame)
        },
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(
                onClick = navigateToWordEntry,
                shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.padding_large))
            ) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.Add,
                    contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.item_entry_title)
                )
            }
        },
    ) { innerPadding ->
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(innerPadding)
                .fillMaxSize()
                .nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection)
        ) {
            HomeBody(
                wordList = dictionaryUiState.wordList,
                onWordClick = navigateToWordUpdate,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(innerPadding)
                    .fillMaxSize()
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun HomeBody(
    wordList: List<Word>, onWordClick: (Int) -> Unit, modifier: Modifier = Modifier
)
{
    if (wordList.isEmpty())
    {
        Text(
            text = stringResource(R.string.no_item_description),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleLarge
        )
    }
    else
    {
        DictionaryList(
            wordList = wordList,
            onWordClick = { onWordClick(it.id) },
            modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.padding_small))
        )
    }
}

@Composable
private fun DictionaryList(
    wordList: List<Word>, onWordClick: (Word) -> Unit, modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    LazyColumn(modifier = modifier, userScrollEnabled = true) {
        items(items = wordList, key = { it.id }) { word ->
            DictionaryWord(word = word,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.padding_small))
                    .clickable { onWordClick(word) })
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    private fun DictionaryWord(word: Word, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
        OutlinedCard(
            modifier = modifier,
           elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(defaultElevation = 4.dp)
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.padding_large)),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.padding_small))
            ) {
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                    ) {
                    Text(
                        text = word.name,
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleLarge,
                    )
                    Text(
                        text = (word.freq.toString()),
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleSmall
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Tried adding and removing columns, every modifier I could find, etc.  I don't need to retain the scroll state when I leave the screen.

That's all, but it says "it looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details", so now I'm going to type a bunch of nothing, which you don't need to read, in hopes that it lets me post a question.  Still not enough talk relative to code?  What's the proper ratio?  These hoops are ridiculous.  Help.  I need an adult.  Is this what the "overflow" in stack overflow refers to?  What's the deal here?  Is this good for anybody?  I need a politician to take the keyboard and fluff this up a bit.  This feels exceedingly unnecessary.  Shpedoinkle!

Answer (score 0):

Solved: nestedScroll statement in the Scaffold AND the one in the Column were interfering with lazyList's scroll authority.  Leaving this up in case any one else has that problem.